# How to tint nodes?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My game has day/night. Is it possible to tint nodes (and their children)?

Not necessarily the *whole* scene (because I don't want to tint my HUD stuff). I managed to overlay the scene with semi-transparent, 960x640 (retina) color image... but, maybe there is a more efficient way to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just tint the affected nodes  - sprites, labels, etc as long as they implement the [CCRGBAProtocol](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/protocol_c_c_r_g_b_a_protocol-p.html).

For example these three colors can be used for daytime, dawn and night:

```
// full brightness
sprite.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
// getting darker
sprite.color = ccc3(200, 200, 220);
// night
sprite.color = ccc3(140, 140, 180);
```

I pulled up the blue channel because blue still feels pretty dark without draining too much of the brightness. You'll see this effect in a lot of games, where night colors actually have a blue-ish tone to them. It's a trick to retain some color and brightness while still giving the feeling of darkness.

These numbers are off the top of my head and certainly will need tweaking. Also you should aim for a subtle effect. "Night" in a game doesn't mean that all graphics are pitch black.

Comment: I think I can't tint a whole tilemap. I could, of course, iterate through every single tile in it and tint it, but that doesn't sound efficient at all.

Comment: True, but you haven't mentioned tilemaps. ;) You can change the color of each tile but that will convert each tile into a CCSprite, which means per tile about 420 Bytes of memory usage. For a 200x200 tilemap with all tiles turned into CCSprite that would consume 16 MB of memory.

Comment: If I edit the color of a tile, the tile "is converted to a CCSprite"? What was the tile *before* doing such then? Why? What other things can convert a tile to a CCSprite? Is such thing reversible?

Comment: Every time you call the CCTMXLayer method -(CCSprite*) tileAt:(CGPoint)pos; Cocos2D will create a CCSprite if this tile position has never been accessed before with tileAt. After calling tileAt, instead of the tile being merely a textured quad a newly created CCSprite instance is added to the CCTMXLayer. The tileAt method is the only way to access a tile in the layer as a CCSprite, so you do have to call tileAt if you want to manipulate a particular tile as a CCSprite instance.

Comment: So is there a better or more efficient way to tint cctmxlayer objects? Perhaps overlay the game world with a semitransparent color layer?

Comment: Overlay is probably better but on 1st/2nd generation devices that imposes a serious performance penalty (fullscreen image WITH alpha).